# Import data from excel to multiple tables in sql server by using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

i have built a window form in c# and import excel file to single  sql table but now i have multiple columns in database and i have to import same excel file in different tables and update it every month.

Is there a way  of importing data to multiple tables?

Comment: use this library  LinqToExcel it's a good one

Comment: Yes the process is similar to what you are doing for a single table, but you have to adjust it for multiple tables. We have no idea what you are doing now or how you are doing it so nobody can offer much advice.